# Preventing user seeing previously submitted info

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I have been given a spec for a web app which will be deployed on public terminals.  This app will accept personal details during a loan application process.

Is it possible to prevent the next customer using back to see the previous applicant's details?

We've considered using AJAX to submit forms in the background, then clearing the fields, but that won't help with pages with displayed data (ie results of an address search).

Comment: Just my opinion but "public terminal", "browser" and "personal details" is the worst possible combination.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's a java issue. It's not a programming issue at all.
Keeping stored information inserted inside a webform is a browser job. You have just to disable this function on the browser you'll use in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the data on the page and use that populate an EJB then call a servlet that will use the bean to process the loan application using the data inside of the bean, clear all of the data out of the bean and then redirect to whatever page comes after the application has been processed. You could alwyas use some javascript to clear the browser's history then there would be no way for anyone to use the go back button. Simplistic examples but they should give you an idea or two on where to start.